# How to get list of documents in the collection till where the sum of 'cost' field has reached a specific value (mongoDb)?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection:

```
[
 {
  _id:1,
  dish:pizza,
  cost:52
 },
 {
  _id:2,
  dish:burger,
  cost:33,
 },
 {
  _id:3,
  dish:sandwich,
  cost:64,
 }
 {
  _id:4,
  dish:noodles,
  cost:23
 },
]
```

I have a budget set equal to some value say 60.

Is it possible to `sort` the dishes by `cost` in `asc` order and get first n number of documents where sum of costs is less than or equal to 60?

here: cost of 23(noodles)+33(burger)<=60, so these 2 documents are fetched.

output should be:

```
[
 {
  _id:4,
  dish:noodles,
  cost:23
 }, 
 {
  _id:2,
  dish:burger,
  cost:33,
 }
]
```

Comment: good question, I don't see any answer with find or aggregation. Maybe try looking for map-reduce (sort and map your documents, and in reduce function add to output while sum<=60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this map-reduce command :

```
// Variable for map
var _map = function () {   
    emit(null,this);
};

// Variable for reduce
var _reduce = function (key, values) {
     var sum = 0;
     var resultArray=[]
for(value in values){
  sum=sum+values[value].cost;
  if(sum<=60){
    resultArray.push(values[value]);
  }
}
var result = {};
result.selected=resultArray;
return result;
}
;

db.runCommand({ 
    mapReduce: "01",
    map: _map,
    reduce: _reduce,
    out: { "inline" : 1},
    query: {},
    sort: {cost:1},
    inputDB: "testing",
 });
})
```

Note sort by cost indicated in command. You can filter your doc before map-reduce with the query object.
It will output

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "value" : {
        "selected" : [
            {
                "_id" : 4, 
                "dish" : "noodles", 
                "cost" : 23
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : 2, 
                "dish" : "burger", 
                "cost" : 33
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Quite easy at this point to access to value.selected to get the results.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!!

Comment: Thing is map reduce is looping through all the documents irrespective of the fact that we have got our `sum(cost)` in first n documents only.
This would cause unnecessary overhead on db.

Comment: just add a break in for in loop to stop it.But it necessary will threat all documents in map function before starting reduce function.

Comment: Break statement will just stop the for loop. Map &reduce will continue to interate till all documents are scanned .

Comment: Map function will threat all documents, and add them in an array which will be threatened by loop in reduce function. So map will threat all documents(except if you filter them before), but loop in reduce will stop when value is reached